# Add child width to parent content

Tags: html, css

I wasnt sure exactly what to write as the title, but my jsfiddle should make everything very clear.

https://jsfiddle.net/1btr7mkq/

```
<div class="blabla">
  Bla bla bla blalblabl bla bla bla bla bla
  <div class="questionMark">?</div>
</div>
```

If I make the output window smaller, there's a sweet spot where the question mark falls into the 2nd line, but the blabla's stay in 1 line.

[image]

How do I avoid this interaction?
I see 2 possible solutions, 
1st one having "reserved" width on the right side for the question mark. That way if text comes within 40ish pixels from the right edge, it will drop it down.

2nd, better solution would be without the reserved width on the right side. In this case, lines above the last line can use full width, and wont linebreak 40px before the end. In this case the page would have to "detect" that the question mark jumped lines, and add a blank line under it's own content.

I've tried a few things but couldn't get either of these to work as I wanted.

Comment: Put the question-mark *before* the text in the source: https://jsfiddle.net/1btr7mkq/1/

Comment: OR add clearing for the float: https://jsfiddle.net/1btr7mkq/2/

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the DIV with the question mark at the beginning of the container DIV. In conjunction with `float: right` this will always put the image in the upper right corner of the container and allows the text to float left and below it:

```
<div class="blabla">
  <div class="questionMark">?</div>
  Bla bla bla blalblabl bla bla bla bla bla
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5cysbv5h/

Answer (score 2):

-Are u looking for this if yes then just remove Float:right and add display:inline
-then the Question mark will always come after Question is completed[image]

Comment: I actually wanted the question mark to be aligned to the right side of the box. The 2 comments on my question helped solve it. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why the **[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** has been created.

```css
.title {
  display:flex;
  background:beige;
  }
.blabla{
  flex-shrink:1;
  flex-grow:1;
  }
.questionMark{
  background:blue;
  color:white;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <div class="blabla">Bla blabla bla</div>
  <div class="questionMark">?</div>
</div>
```

- `flex-grow` allows the element to use more space if available.
- `flex-shrink` allows the element to use less space if unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

is this you want? **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1btr7mkq/4/)**

```
.questionMark{
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 8px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: position may also help

Answer (score 0):

```
  .blabla{
       border: 1px solid #888;
       background-color:#ffffef;
       border-top-left-radius: 10px;
       border-top-right-radius: 10px;
       font-size: 2em;
       padding: 3px 30px;
       position:relative;
       padding-right:50px;
   }
 .questionMark{
      background-color: blue;
      border-radius: 100px;
      clear: both;
       color: white;
      padding: 0 8px;
      cursor:pointer;
      position:absolute;
      right:20px;
     top:3px;   
    }
```

This will work for you